# how to output the hex data back from input file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

How to store a file to unsigned int

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

unsigned int key[4];

int main(){
    ifstream file("key.txt");
    store(file);
    return 0;
}
```

I have this data in my key.txt

```
0xFDA5
0xD54E
0xFC00
0xB55A
```

I created this function

```
void store(ifstream &file){
    int i = 0;
    if(!file)
        cout << "Couldn't open file " << endl;

    while(!file.eof()){

         file >> hex >> key[i];
         i++;
    }

    for( int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ ){
          cout << k[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

I get the number is in hex value . My question is if I want to get back this output

```
0xFDA5
0xD54E
0xFC00
0xB55A
```

which code should I use?

Comment: no. the output i get is all in number example:
65522322

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For uppercase output (e.g. 0XFDA5) edit the `for` loop as follows:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
      cout << std::uppercase << showbase << std::hex << key[i] << endl;
}
```

or

```
for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
       printf("%#X\n", key[i]);
}
```

For lowercase output(e.g. 0xfda5) edit the `for` loop as follows:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
      cout <<  showbase << std::hex << key[i] << endl;
}
```

or

```
for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
       printf("%#x\n", key[i]);
}
```

Comment: work perfectly with the output i want ! thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

As said before, `std::hex` for hexadecimal, `std::showbase` for the 'Ox' prefix and `std::uppercase` for the uppercase.

But what about simply using the STL instead of the `for` loop :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("key.txt");

    copy(
        std::istream_iterator<unsigned int>(file>>std::hex)
        ,std::istream_iterator<unsigned int>()
        ,std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(std::cout<<std::hex<<std::uppercase<<std::showbase,"\n")
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Even if you need a variable to store items :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("key.txt");

    std::vector<unsigned int> keys;
    keys.reserve(4);

    copy(
        std::istream_iterator<unsigned int>(file>>std::hex)
        ,std::istream_iterator<unsigned int>()
        ,back_inserter(keys)
    );

    copy(
        begin(keys)
        ,end(keys)
        ,std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(std::cout<<std::hex<<std::uppercase<<std::showbase,"\n")
    );

    return 0;
}
```